# Regular expression in mysql to find w/2

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a query as below, Which will select all rows which contain `GB:2` and the word `Samsung` also there with in three word.

But my data sometimes contain `GB-2` or `GB,3` etc. So I want to change my query as `GB*` so that it will take any character and alphabet after `GB`.

How I can put this `GB*` in my query?

```
SELECT description from mobile 
where content REGEXP '[[:<:]]GB:2( [^ ]+){0,3} Samsung[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: You can use: `'[[:<:]]GB[^ ]*( [^ ]+){0,3} Samsung[[:>:]]'`

Comment: How about `where content like '%GB%' and content like '$Samsung%'` ?

Comment: anubahva, you are rigth...great